# How to calculate the average by a unique identifier on Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assuming i have a data with multiple repetition of unique identifiers, how do i calculate the average by these unique identifiers. The actual data has 10,000 rows so it is difficult to do a filter and sort to calculate the average. it becomes very exhaustive and manual for me.

Comment: Look into AVERAGEIFS() or a Pivot Table.

Comment: And also if you select your cells, excel will show the average on the bottom of the editor (at least it's working for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on `Gary Student`'s layout, If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

[image]

For all the Chairs,
Total Quantity: 28+13+5 = 46
Total Price: (28*12) + (13*14) + (5*22) = 628
Weighted Average Price: 628/46 = 13.65217391

I have the following formulas

`G2` : `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$9,$F2,$B$2:$B$9)`

`H2` : `=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$9,$F2,$C$2:$C$9)`

`I2` : `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$9*$C$2:$C$9)*($A$2:$A$9=$F2))/SUMIF($A$2:$A$9,$F2,$B$2:$B$9)`

Comment: Thank you so much Aubs. Your answer was so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following very simple example:

[image]

The identifiers are in column **A** and the values to be averaged are in column **B**.  The formula in **E1** is:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B$1:$B$9,$A$1:$A$9,D1)
```

Comment: Thank you Gary's student for your answer. I apologize. I actually forgot to include that I am taking a weighted average so assuming the unique identifier is a chair where 12,14,22 are the prices for the chairs and 28,13,5 are the numbers of chairs available respectively to the price. Thus, there are  28 chairs available for $12  and so on. How can I find the weighted average price for the chairs as well as other unique identifiers without manually dividing the sum of price by the sum of the volume? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know all of the unique values in your observations (column A), then, using the layout shown by Aubs, you could also write in F2:  =UNIQUE($A2:$A)

That will return a column array with the unique values, and you can then use the rest of the solution suggested by Aubs.